# RecylerView Horizontal como WhatsApp

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês de como fazer este layout da parte "Mídia" em um determinado Contato do WhatsApp. Seria este `CardView` inteiro chamado de "Mídia".

[image: CardView Midia do WhatsApp]

Seria quase exatamente desse mesmo jeito, não tenho dúvida quanto aos adapters, apenas dúvida em relação ao xml do layout. As imagens também seriam todas de mesmo tamanho neste quadrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você cria um *RecyclerView* tem que lhe atribuir um *LayoutManager*. Neste  caso(lista horizontal) atribua um [LinearLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html) especificando `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` no [construtor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#LinearLayoutManager%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean%29):

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
                                                      LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView midiaList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.a_sua_recycler_view);
midiaList.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Comment: E como os itens do RecyclerView irão ficar naquele tamanho específico? Todos quadrados exatamente como da imagem?

Comment: Os quadrados podem ser obtidos usando uma CardView como pai das tuas rows

Comment: Me refiro aos quadrados dentro de mídia e não os externos que são CardViews. Os quadrados são as imagens exibidas em lista dentro de um recycler view horizontal.

Comment: Julgo que isso depende do layout que define cada linha(coluna neste caso) do RecyclerView.

Comment: Das duas uma. Ou sao simples imageviews com cantos arredondados, ou entao é outra recyclerview mas com orientaçao vertical

Comment: @PedroOliveira não olhe para os cardviews, olhe apenas para o que está debaixo do texto Mídia.

Comment: exatamente isto que o @ramaral falou que também quero saber.

Comment: Como pode ser vertical se as imagens são exibidas na horizontal?

Comment: @ramaral testei o que você colocou na resposta  deu certo. Também consegui definir as imagens que nem no WhatsApp, escolhi um pouco maior para cada item da lista que foi 96dp. O problema agora foi que o recyclerview não fica "wrap_content" mesmo definindo sua altura assim. Ele toma todo os espaço restante como se estivesse "match_parent". Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Lucas, o melhor é você criar uma nova pergunta onde deve postar o xml dessa parte e se possível uma imagem.